# Create empty folders in r and name them based on column values

Tags: r, directory

I'd like to create a folder containing empty folders that correspond to values of the ID column of my dataset. There are over 1000 rows in the column.

Here is an example:

| IDs | People |
| --- | --- |
| 124 | Jim |
| 345 | Mary |
| 675 | Hilary |
| 897 | Chris |
| 235 | John. |

I want the name of the folders to be 124, 345, 675, etc.
I would like to find an answer similar to the one that was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786946/create-empty-text-files-in-r-and-name-them-based-on-column-values) for creating empty text files.

Comment: `sapply(your_data$IDs, dir.create)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you. `dir.create()` is not working for me. I'm getting the following error: "Error in match.fun(FUN) : 'dir.create(file.path(mainDir, subDir))' is not a function, character or symbol"

Comment: I found my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65179027/create-folders-and-subfolders-based-on-two-variables]